# i want to display all checkboxes value which are checked

Tags: php, checkbox, wordpress, checked

I want to display all checked checkboxes in php.

```
<script>
    function RequestObject () 
    {
        var ReturnValue = null;
        try { 
            ReturnValue = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        }
        catch (Error) {
            try { 
                ReturnValue = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.HTTP"); 
            }
            catch (Error) {
                try { 
                    ReturnValue = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
                }
                catch (Error) { 
                    // failed 
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return ReturnValue;
    }
    var requestObj = null;        
    function coajax(sender)
    {
        requestObj = RequestObject();
        if (requestObj)
        {
            sender.enabled = false; // so a user cannot change till request finished
            requestObj.open('get', '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/lunch_dinner.php?lid=' + sender.value, true);
            requestObj.onreadystatechange = coajax_finish;
            requestObj.send(null);
        }
    }
    function coajax_finish()
    {
        if (requestObj.readyState == 4)
        {
            document.getElementById('ldb_target').innerHTML = requestObj.responseText;
            document.getElementById('ldb').enabled = true;
        }
    }
    function getDays(select){
        var selectedString = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        if(selectedString == "Bespoke Days"){
            document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "block"; 
        }
        else { 
            document.getElementById("days_target").style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
    function validateForm()
    {
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["contract"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="" || x=="Select Contract")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to select contract type! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["days"].selectedIndex;
        if (x<1) 
        {
            alert("Please select days");
            return false;
        }
        else if(x==4) { // fifth entry 
            var checked = false, 
            chk = document.forms["form1"]["day"];
            for (var i = 0; i < chk.length; i++) 
            {
                if (chk[i].checked) { checked=true; break }
            }
            if (!checked) {
                alert("At least one day should be checked.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["ldb"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="" || x=="Select")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to select lunch-dinner! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["ldb"].value;
        if(x=="Lunch" || x=="Both")
        {
            var y=document.forms["form1"]["lunch"].value;
            if(y=="Lunch")
            {
                alert("Oh, you forgot to select lunch time! :)");
                return false;
            }
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["ldb"].value;
        if(x=="Dinner" || x=="Both")
        {
            var y=document.forms["form1"]["dinner"].value;
            if(y=="Dinner")
            {
                alert("Oh, you forgot to select dinner time! :)");
                return false;
            }
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["phone"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to enter your Phone Number! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x = document.form1.phone.value;
        if(isNaN(x)||x.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
        {
            alert("Please enter Numaric value in contact number.")
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["meal"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="" || x=="Select Meal")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to select meal preference! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["fnm"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to enter your Full Name! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["pcod"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to enter your Postal Code! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to enter your Email Address! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["email"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
        {
            alert("Excuse me! Valid Email Address Please!");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["add"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to enter your Address! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["rate"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to enter Rate! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["rate"].value;
        if(isNaN(x)||x.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
        {
            alert("Please enter Numaric value in Rate.")
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["amount"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
            alert("Oh, you forgot to enter Amount! :)");
            return false;
        }
        var x=document.forms["form1"]["amount"].value;
        if(isNaN(x)||x.indexOf(" ")!=-1)
        {
            alert("Please enter Numaric value in Total Amount.")
            return false;
        }
    }
    function calculateTotal(rate)
    {
        var rate=(document.forms["form1"]["rate"].value) * 1.03;
        document.forms["form1"]["amount"].value = rate;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <table class="order-paypal" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td><span>Choose contract</span></td>
            <td>
                <select name="contract">
                    <option value="Select Contract" selected>Select Contract</option>
                    <option value="7 meal veg contract">7 meal veg contract</option>
                    <option value="7 meal nonveg contract">7 meal nonveg contract</option>
                    <option value="7 meal nonveg contract">7 meal nonveg contract</option>
                    <option value="8 meal veg contract">8 meal veg contract</option>
                    <option value="8 meal nonveg contract">8 meal nonveg contract</option>
                    <option value="8 meal mix contract">8 meal mix contract</option>
                    <option value="9 meal veg contract">9 meal veg contract</option>
                    <option value="9 meal nonveg contract ">9 meal nonveg contract  </option>
                    <option value="9 meal mix contract ">9 meal mix contract  </option>
                    <option value="30 meal veg contract">30 meal veg contract</option>
                    <option value="30 meal nonveg contract">30 meal nonveg contract</option>
                    <option value="30 meal mix contract">30 meal mix contract</option>
                    <option value="Book-a-cook service">Book-a-cook service</option>
                    <option value="Extra roti/rice/dal/vegetable">Extra roti/rice/dal/vegetable</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Please enter days required</span></td>
            <td>
                <select name="days" id="days" onchange="getDays(this)">
                    <option value="Select Days" selected>Select Days</option>
                    <option value="Mon-Fri">Mon-Fri</option>
                    <option value="Mon-Sat">Mon-Sat</option>
                    <option value="Mon-Sun">Mon-Sun</option>
                    <option value="Bespoke Days">Bespoke Days</option>
                </select>

                <ul id="days_target" style="display:none;">
                    <span>Select Days</span>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><span>Please mention Lunch or Dinner or both</span></td>
            <td>
                <select name="ldb" id="ldb" onchange="coajax(this);" >
                    <option value="Select" selected>Select</option>
                    <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
                    <option value="Dinner">Dinner</option>
                    <option value="Both">Both</option>
                </select>
                <span id="ldb_target"></span><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Please mention your contact number</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="phone" /></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td><span>Please mention your meal preference</span></td>
            <td>
                <select name="meal" >
                    <option value="Select Meal" selected>Select Meal</option>
                    <option value="Punjabi">Punjabi</option>
                    <option value="Gujarati">Gujarati</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;"><span>Please mention any dietary requirements</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="req" ></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td><span>Full name</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fnm" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Address</span></td>
            <td><textarea name="add" ></textarea></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><span>Postal code</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pcod" ></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td><span>Email</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" ></td>
        </tr>               
        <tr>
            <td><span>Enter amount to pay</span></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="rate" >
                <br />
                (<a target="_blank" href="http://www.infozzle.com/yatin/tifffin_planet/prices-and-offers-2/">Check the rate of your item and your zone</a>)
                <br/>
                Card charge: 3% of the total amount
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Total Amount</span></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount" value="Click here to see total amount" onclick="calculateTotal(this);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <table class="submit">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitbtn" class="submit-payment"/></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" class="submit-reset"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I want to display all checked checkboxes of "day" on action page by this code:

```
<?php 
    foreach($day as $k)
    { 
        echo $k.","; 
    }
?>
```

html Form and action page are in template page of wordpress. 
but it doesn't work.how to do?i have written this code.

Comment: do you have the <form> tags in your html? please show the complete code.

Comment: Are you submitting your form ? Show your complete form ?

Comment: I did this with a submit button by submitting the form. It works cool

Comment: yes i m submitting the form.

Comment: @Avnee.Angel Are you getting any error? Share your entire form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
  <form name="search_field" id="search_field" action="formpage.php" method="post" >
    <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
     <li><input type="checkbox"  name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  />
    </form>
```

You can get the working result from this (For your better understanding):

```
 <form name="search_field" id="search_field" action="formpage.php" method="post" >
 <?php if(!$_POST == ''){ ?>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("mon", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("tue", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("wed", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("thr", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("fri", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("sat", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array("sun", $_POST['day'])) {?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  />
</form>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<?php } else { ?>


 <form name="search_field" id="search_field" action="formpage.php" method="post" >
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
 <li><input type="checkbox"  name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"  />
</form>



<?php } ?>
```

Just create the formpage.php file, paste the above code and check the result.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<form name="frmli" action="" method="post"><ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></li>
</ul>

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
foreach($_POST['day'] as $day)
{
echo $day." ";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I checked, and its working, did you add the submit button and form?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the form tag set like this: **`method="post"`**. also first check to see that the `POST['day']` has been set or not. I used count() in this situation. I added the if else statement so that if your `$_POST['day']` is empty, you'll at least be echoing that it's empty.

```
<form name="frmli" action="" method="POST">
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="mon"/>Monday</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="tue"/>Tueday</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="wed"/>Wednesday</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="thr"/>Thursday</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="fri"/>Friday</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sat"/>Saturday</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sun"/>Sunday</li>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</ul>
</form>
<?php

if(empty($_POST['day'])){
    echo "none of the boxes were checked";
}else{
    $N = count($_POST['day']);
    echo("You selected $N door(s): ");
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
        echo($_POST['day'][$i] . " ");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: try this code and tell me if it works out, if not what does the error say?

Comment: when you first load the page, and nothing is in your $_POST['day'] array, your code will have an error because it's empty, yet you're trying to echo it through looping. You need to have the code first check if the array is empty or not. Other than that. Be sure to add the form tags (closing form tags as well) and the submit button.

Comment: actually i changed checkboxes group to individual checkbox.and then after i verified if it is checked or not.